# WPF Image source turns null by itself

Tags: wpf, image, canvas

I have a `Canvas`, into which I put `Image`s, like:

```
Image img = new Image()
{
    Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(cardImages[0].Last(), UriKind.Relative))
};

CardStackCanvas1.Children.Add(img);
CardStackCanvas1.InvalidateVisual();
```

After these lines, if I check the children of the `Canvas`, the `Image` is there, as it should, with the proper `Source`.

If I then, after the method in which I add the `Image` finishes, look at what the `Canvas` contains (by for example creating a MouseUp event), the `Image` is still there, but it's `Source` is now `null`. I'm clueless right now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you change the `cardImages` array elements, which are image sources. You should provide another variable for image source.

Solution:

```
string imageSourceString = cardImages[0].Last();
Image img = new Image()
{
    Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imageSourceString, UriKind.Relative))
};
```

Comment: You assumption is wrong. The BitmapImage created from the first `cardImages` element won't change when you later change the array.